# How can I know the amount of documents modified by monk?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I'm using **Monk** to connect to to **MongoDB** from **NodeJS**.

I am trying to pull an item from an array, and for that purpose I'm using

```
db.collection('MYCOLLECTION').update({_id:id},{$pull:{reviews:{userId:userId}}, function(err,data){
  console.log(data);
})
```

When I execute this sentence directly in Mongo (through the console), the function returns an object with three properties:

- nMatched
- nUpserted
- nModified

However, when I do the same thing using monk, I am only getting a value '1' which I supposed is the value of the property nMatched. Is there a way for me to get the nModified property?

Comment: The information will not be returned in the same way as the shell, but the retuned value will be the modified count, But as with all callbacks the first argument is the `err` object, so you need two arguments to get anything meaningful. `function(err,numAffected)`

Comment: Sorry that in my question, the code part is incorrect, I do have two parameters, however I'm always getting '1' in the second parameter even though nothing has been modified.